# Проверить, что элементы показаны на странице (улучшить код)

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="left-img">
    <img id="pic" src="/images/pic.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<script>
    if ($(".left-img").is(":visible"))
    {
        $("#pic").load(function() {
            /* выполнить действие */
        });
    }
</script>
```

`div.left-img` может принимать CSS `.left-img {display: none;}`, а картинка может не подгрузиться с сервера.
Требуется выполнить некоторое действие если элемент `left-img` показывается в браузере и картинка `/images/pic.jpg` была загружена и показана в браузере.

Читаю следующее: Событие load происходит, когда сам элемент и все его дочерние элементы полностью загружены.
Код работает, но проблема в том что указывая `$(".left-img").load(...` он не проверяет дочерние элементы, еще мне кажется, что это все можно объединить, как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала убедитесь что ваш скрипт расположен ниже самой библиотеки `jQuery`.

И вызывайте следующим образом:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){    
          $("#pic").load(function() {
                /* выполнить действие */
          });
    });
<script>
```

или

```
<script>
    $(function(){
         $("#pic").load(function() {
                /* выполнить действие */
         });
    });
<script>
```

В данном случае скрипт будет выполнен после полной загрузки страницы.

Comment: а так же не обязательно _в конце_ страницы, главное _после_ элементов которые будут использоваться в скрипте

Comment: @Alex, да, согласен. Разницы нет, но раскидывать JS по всему файлу тоже не совсем правильно, хоть и не запрещается.

Comment: @Alex, по каким правилам?

Comment: @Grundy сложившимся правилам верстки) тот же гугл при  анализе страницы будет мягко намекать, что лучше не разбрасывать скрипты по всей странице, а держать в `head`. Правило не обязательное, но предпочтительное.

Comment: @Alex, допустим имеем 700Кб скриптов в `<head>`. Страница будет грузиться нормально, без подтормозок? (страница не кэшируется на стороне пользователя)

Comment: @ZeJur а почему у Вас должны возникнуть тормоза из-за 700 кб js при сегодняшних реалиях? Да и правило, как написано выше, предпочтительное, но не обязательное, все зависит от проекта, Вы вполне можете подключать js характерный для конкретного шаблона при использовании таковых.

Comment: @Alex, Ок, отошли от темы ) В любом случае, совет поместить скрипт в конце страниц был дан дабы исключить его размещение до самой библиотеки jQuery. Остальное на вкус и цвет! )

Comment: @ZeJur в таком случае возможно Вам стоит изменить текст ответа, дописав данную информацию.

Comment: @Alex, сейчас подправлю, чтоб больше споров не возникло )